# sort lines in file based on specific location character

Tags: file, shell, unix, sorting, solaris

I want to sort a file based on specific character in a .txt file.

**This is a file given to me:**

```
12345678901234567890123456789012345
header     1stfoo   DDMMYYYY 2ndfoo
sltele     Hoodie   24051988 d12Hdq
sltele     Hoodie   07051987 d30Hdq
sltele     Hoodie   07082011 d08Hdq
sltele     Hoodie   09081961 d04Hdq
sltele     Hoodie   20041962 d14Hdq
sltele     Hoodie   20032000 d01Hdq
sltele     Hoodie   13062002 d05Hdq
```

As you can see there is a column contains date with DDMMYYY format. If I sort it with  `sort -n -k 3,3 thisfile.txt > sortedfile.txt` i got this result:

```
sltele     Hoodie   07051987 d30Hdq
sltele     Hoodie   07082011 d08Hdq
sltele     Hoodie   09081961 d04Hdq
sltele     Hoodie   13062002 d05Hdq
sltele     Hoodie   20032000 d01Hdq
sltele     Hoodie   20041962 d14Hdq
sltele     Hoodie   24051988 d12Hdq
```

but, I want the result like this:

```
sltele     Hoodie   09081961 d04Hdq
sltele     Hoodie   20041962 d14Hdq
sltele     Hoodie   07051987 d30Hdq
sltele     Hoodie   24051988 d12Hdq
sltele     Hoodie   20032000 d01Hdq
sltele     Hoodie   13062002 d05Hdq
sltele     Hoodie   07082011 d08Hdq
```

As a valid sortedfile.txt based on DDMMYYYY date format.

can somebady help me?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the sort command, specifying multiple keys, and key start end positions:

```
sort -n -k 3.8,3.12 -k 3.6,3.7 -k 3.4,3.5 < input_file
```

output:

```
sltele     Hoodie   09081961 d04Hdq
sltele     Hoodie   07051987 d30Hdq
sltele     Hoodie   24051988 d12Hdq
sltele     Hoodie   20032000 d01Hdq
sltele     Hoodie   20042000 d14Hdq
sltele     Hoodie   13062002 d05Hdq
sltele     Hoodie   07082011 d08Hdq
```

from sort man-page:

> KEYDEF is F[.C][OPTS][,F[.C][OPTS]] for start and stop position, where
>   F is a field number  and C a character position in the field; both are
>   origin 1 ... characters in a field are counted from the beginning of
>   the preceding whitespace.

Comment: yes... that's the solution I wanted... Thank you very much perreal :)

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer doen't actually answer the question of sorting on a specific range of absolute character positions, counting from the beginning of the line (which is position 1 as counted by `sort`).

It is important to remember that for `sort`, field numbers refer to portions of text separated by the *field separator*, which is a non-blank to blank transition unless changed with the `-t`/`--field-separator=SEP` option.
The correct way to sort on a range of absolute character positions counted from the beginning of the line is to count characters starting from field number 1, like so:

```
sort -k 1.STARTPOS,1.ENDPOS
```

You can leave off the `1.ENDPOS` if you want the sort key to extend to the 
end of the line.

Confusing field numbers with absolute character positions can lead to surprising (and often very frustrating) results.

Answer (score 0):

I know there's a better way to do this, but this is what I've done in the past, rarely having to sort files.

```
sed -e 's/\([0-9]\{2\}\)\([0-9]\{2\}\)\([0-9]\{4\}\)/\3\2\1/g' thisfile.txt | \
   sort -n -k 3,3 | \
   sed -e 's/\([0-9]\{4\}\)\([0-9]\{2\}\)\([0-9]\{2\}\)/\3\2\1/g' > sortedfile.txt
```